How do I cite linkedin apa7
The APA has a special formatting requirement for LinkedIn profiles.
According to the APA guidelines, I need:

Rudra, P. (n.d.). Home [LinkedIn page]. LinkedIn. Retrieved November 22, 2024, from https://uk.linkedin.com/in/pravinarudra

However, the profile currently renders like this:

Rudra, P. (n.d.). LinkedIn. Home [LinkedIn page].  Retrieved November 22, 2024, from https://uk.linkedin.com/in/pravinarudra

The italics in the journal field extend too far, and the journal and title fields need to swap. How can I fix this reference?
essay.tex
\documentclass[stu,donotrepeattitle]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array,fancyvrb,graphicx,verbatim,xurl}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Times New Roman

\addbibresource{./references.bib}

% Title and Short Title
\title{Title}
\shorttitle{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

references.bib
@article{linkedin_Rudra,
  author = {Rudra , Pravina},
  url = {https://uk.linkedin.com/in/pravinarudra},
  title = {Linkedin},
  journal = {Home [LinkedIn page]},
  urldate = {2024-11-22},
}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... And please show us what you want to get.

Thank you for the welcome :)
I updated so that if you make a new directory with essay.tex and references.bib containing those snippets it should show my current output.

Off-topic: The mathptmx font package is borderline obsolete. Do consider using the newtxtext and newtxmath font packages instead. This may be done by replacing \usepackage{mathptmx} with \usepackage{newtx}.

In addition, the instruction \usepackage[style=apa, sortcites=true, sorting=nyt, backend=biber]{biblatex} should be simplified to \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}. You should omit the options sortcites=true and sorting=nyt as they can do nothing but conflict with the APA7 guidelines; you needn't specify backend=biber as it's the default. In fact, it's been the default for about a decade by now.

Thank you Mico, this is my first true document, so I went with the format the guide suggested   Where can I find the best information about formatting?

The @article entry type should only be used for pieces published in journals. For the entry at hand, it would be more appropriate to use either the @misc entry type
@misc{linkedin_Rudra,
  author  = {Rudra, Pravina},
  url     = {https://uk.linkedin.com/in/pravinarudra},
  title   = {\textit{Home} [{LinkedIn} page]},
  organization = {\textup{LinkedIn}},
  urldate = {2024-11-22},
}

or the @online entry type
@online{linkedin_Rudra,
  author  = {Rudra, Pravina},
  url     = {https://uk.linkedin.com/in/pravinarudra},
  title   = {Home \textup{[{LinkedIn} page]}},
  organization = {LinkedIn},
  urldate = {2024-11-22},
}

The \textit and \textup commands are needed to make the formatted entry conform to the APA formatting rules. Also, note the curly braces around the word LinkedIn in the title field; the braces are needed to prevent the word from being converted to all-lowercase.


\documentclass{apa7}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@misc{linkedin_Rudra,
  author  = {Rudra, Pravina},
  url     = {https://uk.linkedin.com/in/pravinarudra},
  title   = {\textit{Home} [{LinkedIn} page]},
  organization = {\textup{LinkedIn}},
  urldate = {2024-11-22},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{newtx} % not 'mathptmx'
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=black}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./references.bib}

% Title and Short Title
\title{Title}
\shorttitle{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent
\cite{linkedin_Rudra}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


Thank you so much!! Last night I tried swapping the @article title and journal to get the desired order then using \emph to change the italics. But I can see that this way is much better. Thank you :)

@Smeagol - You're most welcome. The fact that there's no meaningful journal name here to place in the journal field should definitely give you pause about employing the @article entry type.
